# Change styling of marker added by script

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm learning the Google Maps API and following the [earthquakes example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-quakes) on their website. I've read the documentation and spent several hours trying to figure this out, but with no luck.

The example adds their markers by `.addGeoJson` and styles them using a function that changes them into circles which vary in size based on earthquake magnitude. I'm trying to create an additional marker in the script and style it using the same styling function, but I can't figure out how to apply the function to the new marker. What I've done:

```
// My addition:
newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat:20, lng: -160},
  map: map,
  mag: 2
});

// The markers from .loadGeoJson are styled by calling this function but 
// apparently it doesn't apply to the new marker
map.data.setStyle(styleFeature);
```

I guess the `newMarker` isn't added to the default data layer object, where the other markers probably reside?
[Full jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2g61rvu4/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Currently you are making a "normal" Marker (not using the DataLayer).  To style that the same way as the data layer markers are styled, create a function that makes a marker styling it the same way:

```
function createMarker(latLng, mag) {
  var low = [151, 83, 34]; // color of mag 1.0
  var high = [5, 69, 54]; // color of mag 6.0 and above
  var minMag = 1.0;
  var maxMag = 6.0;

  // fraction represents where the value sits between the min and max
  var fraction = (Math.min(mag, maxMag) - minMag) /
    (maxMag - minMag);

  var color = interpolateHsl(low, high, fraction);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      strokeWeight: 0.5,
      strokeColor: '#fff',
      fillColor: color,
      fillOpacity: 2 / mag,
      // while an exponent would technically be correct, quadratic looks nicer
      scale: mag
    },
    zIndex: Math.floor(mag),
    map: map
  });
  return marker;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/a3uynghs/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map, showing styled marker]

2. If you want to add the location to the data layer and have the data layer style it, then you need to do that:

```
  map.data.add({
    geometry: new google.maps.Data.Point({
      lat: 20,
      lng: -160
    }),
    properties: {
    mag: 2
    }
  });
```

Then it will be styled like all the others

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/a3uynghs/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map with added point geometry]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 20,
      lng: -160
    },
    zoom: 2,
    styles: mapStyle
  });
  map.data.add({
    geometry: new google.maps.Data.Point({
      lat: 20,
      lng: -160
    }),
    properties: {
      mag: 2
    }
  });

  map.data.setStyle(styleFeature);

  // Get the earthquake data (JSONP format)
  // This feed is a copy from the USGS feed, you can find the originals here:
  //   http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute(
    'src',
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/quakes.geo.json');
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

// Defines the callback function referenced in the jsonp file.
function eqfeed_callback(data) {
  map.data.addGeoJson(data);
}

function styleFeature(feature) {
  var low = [151, 83, 34]; // color of mag 1.0
  var high = [5, 69, 54]; // color of mag 6.0 and above
  var minMag = 1.0;
  var maxMag = 6.0;

  // fraction represents where the value sits between the min and max
  var fraction = (Math.min(feature.getProperty('mag'), maxMag) - minMag) /
    (maxMag - minMag);

  var color = interpolateHsl(low, high, fraction);

  return {
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      strokeWeight: 0.5,
      strokeColor: '#fff',
      fillColor: color,
      fillOpacity: 2 / feature.getProperty('mag'),
      // while an exponent would technically be correct, quadratic looks nicer
      scale: Math.pow(feature.getProperty('mag'), 2)
    },
    zIndex: Math.floor(feature.getProperty('mag'))
  };
}


function interpolateHsl(lowHsl, highHsl, fraction) {
  var color = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // Calculate color based on the fraction.
    color[i] = (highHsl[i] - lowHsl[i]) * fraction + lowHsl[i];
  }

  return 'hsl(' + color[0] + ',' + color[1] + '%,' + color[2] + '%)';
}

var mapStyle = [{
  'featureType': 'all',
  'elementType': 'all',
  'stylers': [{
    'visibility': 'off'
  }]
}, {
  'featureType': 'landscape',
  'elementType': 'geometry',
  'stylers': [{
    'visibility': 'on'
  }, {
    'color': '#fcfcfc'
  }]
}, {
  'featureType': 'water',
  'elementType': 'labels',
  'stylers': [{
    'visibility': 'off'
  }]
}, {
  'featureType': 'water',
  'elementType': 'geometry',
  'stylers': [{
    'visibility': 'on'
  }, {
    'hue': '#5f94ff'
  }, {
    'lightness': 60
  }]
}];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```